# Trying to calculate cummulative sum in tsql

Tags: sql, t-sql

What am I doing wrong here?
The result is an error, saying:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near 'order'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 25 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'as'.

---

```
select *
, Antal + Normtid as Flextid
, SUM(antal) OVER (PARTITION BY transdate ORDER BY tekst)
, x = row_number() over (partition by åruge order by tekst)

from
(
    select *
    ,
    (
        select b.antal
        from bi.dbo.Table_pg_FlextidsopgørelseGlUdgave b
        where b.tekst = bi.dbo.Table_pg_FlextidsopgørelseGlUdgave.tekst
        and b.transdate = bi.dbo.Table_pg_FlextidsopgørelseGlUdgave.transdate
        and b.åruge = bi.dbo.Table_pg_FlextidsopgørelseGlUdgave.åruge
        and b.type = 'Normtid'
    ) as Normtid

    from
    bi.dbo.Table_pg_FlextidsopgørelseGlUdgave
    where type = 'afholdt'

    and tekst = 'fs'
    --and åruge = '201501'
) as data
order by tekst, transdate
```

Regards

Peter

Comment: select * is only allowed when nothing else selected. Do select table.*,  instead.

Comment: Maybe the first Select doesn't know the column tekst. I prefer listing all columns always and avoiding *

Comment: Yes, listing all columns in the select list is even better!

Comment: Thank you Jarlh and DangeMask. I DID NOT help.

Comment: Thank you, Jarl and DangeMask. I did not help.       I Tried select ansat_i_afdeling, område, [type], antal, år, måned, dag, ugenr, åruge, medarbejderstatus, senestopdateret, normtid, tekst, transdate
, Antal + Normtid as Flextid
, SUM(antal) OVER (PARTITION BY transdate ORDER BY tekst)

Comment: DATA and TYPE are reserved words by some dbms products. (But not in ANSI SQL.) Double quote them as "DATA" and "TYPE"! (Or perhaps [DATA] and [TYPE].)

Comment: It did not help to [] Data and Type. The strange thing is, that it is running if I outcomment the Sum(antal) .....

Comment: Are you using SQL Server and if so what version?

Comment: sql server 2003 ( I guess)

Comment: I don't think `Over` is valid in versions before 2008. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Comment: Row_number() over is also a 2008 function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx I would say your Sum and Row_number over's are what are causing your issue. Try you query in sql fiddle and see if it works there

Comment: SQl server 2003?paste the output of select @@version here

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5069.00 (Intel X86)   Aug 22 2012 16:01:52   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

Comment: My answer to this would simply be upgrade your SQL Server to a more recent version.

Comment: Thank you Christian. If I only could deside so, but my boss ...

Comment: As The problem seems to be, that sum over is only available for 2012, I raise the question : Is there another way to calculate a running total. If not I'll have to find another way to solve my challenge. Thank you / Mange tak for hjælpen

Comment: Yes there will be a way to do it but I think it warrants a new question. I think over is available from "2008 R2" and above

Comment: SQL Server 2008 with over on SQL Fiddle, presumably using 2008 R2 - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9b6fb/1/0

Answer (score 2):

It is obvious that you have inappropriate version of `Sql Server`. Cumulative sums with `order by` clause like:

```
SUM(antal) OVER (PARTITION BY transdate ORDER BY tekst)
```

are only available from `Sql Server 2012+`. 
Actually I can reproduce those errors on `Sql Server 2008`:

[image]

This is on `Sql Server 2012`:

[image]

Notice how the error message changes.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are getting data from derived table is not correct..

**EX:**

```
create table  
sales  
(
id int
)

insert into sales  
values  
(1),  
(2),  
(3)
```

derived table should always have table alias and parent table should refer using from

----this is valid

```
select
* from 
(
select id+1 as id1
from sales
) b
```

--this is not valid

```
select 
* 
(select 
id from sales
)b
```

--Above is valid when you have a subquery say

```
   select 
    id,(select t1.name from table t1 where t1.id=t2.id)as custname
    from table t2
```

coming to your question..this is not valid.I see both table types are same

```
select *
    ,
    (
        select b.antal
        from bi.dbo.Table_pg_FlextidsopgørelseGlUdgave b
        where b.tekst = bi.dbo.Table_pg_FlextidsopgørelseGlUdgave.tekst
        and b.transdate = bi.dbo.Table_pg_FlextidsopgørelseGlUdgave.transdate
        and b.åruge = bi.dbo.Table_pg_FlextidsopgørelseGlUdgave.åruge
        and b.type = 'Normtid'
    ) as Normtid

    from
    bi.dbo.Table_pg_FlextidsopgørelseGlUdgave
    where type = 'afholdt'

    and tekst = 'fs'
    --and åruge = '201501'
```

So you can write something like below

```
select *
, Antal + Normtid as Flextid
, SUM(antal) OVER (PARTITION BY transdate ORDER BY tekst)
, x = row_number() over (partition by åruge order by tekst)

from
(
    select * from 

    (
        select b.antal
        from bi.dbo.Table_pg_FlextidsopgørelseGlUdgave b
        where b.tekst = bi.dbo.Table_pg_FlextidsopgørelseGlUdgave.tekst
        and b.transdate = bi.dbo.Table_pg_FlextidsopgørelseGlUdgave.transdate
        and b.åruge = bi.dbo.Table_pg_FlextidsopgørelseGlUdgave.åruge
        and b.type = 'Normtid'
        and b.type='afholdt'
        and b.tekst = 'fs'

    ) as Normtid

order by tekst, transdate
```

Comment: Select *, (subquery) as subquery from table is valid in tsql

Comment: That is valid in subquery and from question its not clear that whether he is trying to do a subquery.I will add that to answer.thanks